# OpenCV xphoto function

Tags: ios, opencv

I am following the textbook `iOS Application Development with OpenCV 3` and one of the samples uses the function [`cv::xphoto::autowbGrayworld`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/daa/group__xphoto.html). I am using opencv 3.2 but it doesn't seem to have this function.

Is there an alternative or will I have to use opencv 3.1 in order to use that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading the same part of this book. Same error when I use OpenCV 3.2.

After check the OpenCV doc.

> 3.1: 
>   http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/daa/group__xphoto.html#gafaaa144cd2628bf65b115c538cfb50fb
>
> 3.2:
>   http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d71/classcv_1_1xphoto_1_1GrayworldWB.html

Obviously, we should use `GrayWorldWB` instead. Like that:

```
    switch (originalMat.type()) {
        case CV_8UC1:
            // Mono color to RGB
            cv::cvtColor(originalMat, originalMat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
            break;
        case CV_8UC4:
            // RGBA to RGB
            cv::cvtColor(originalMat, originalMat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
            // FALL_THROW
        case CV_8UC3:
            // Adjust the whtie balance
            cv::xphoto::createGrayworldWB()->balanceWhite(originalMat, originalMat);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I can see that works well when I use white overload photo (with RGB or RGBA channels). If balancer not work, make sure that image color mode is not Gray.